# Splash screen with facebook sdk login that needs nohistory=false (I need nohistory=true)

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I have the typical splash screen with a "Connect with Facebook" login button.
When the user triggers the facebook auth, the facebook app pops-up and then comes back to the splash screen in order to call next activity in the onComplete() facebook callback method.

Then from this new created Activity, when the user presses back I go back to the splash screen and I don't want that.
I cannot set the splashscreen to be nohistory=true because the facebook sdk needs to come back to this activity and call the onActivityResult method...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can call splash.finish() after starting the next activity

Comment: I changed my comment to an answer, then you can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can call splash.finish() after starting the next activity